# Word cloud with scaled color according to frequency

Tags: r

I need to create a colored word cloud by the same color but with scaled intensity.
This is an example but used in case of the map.

[image]

As you see the map is colored by one color but with different intensity according to the number of the customer as it is presented in the scale on right.

This is my data frame :

```
> head(d,20)
                   word freq
paris             paris 1250
saint             saint 1247
les                 les  694
marseille     marseille  500
lyon               lyon  312
toulouse       toulouse  226
nantes           nantes  204
strasbourg   strasbourg  177
seine             seine  174
montpellier montpellier  170
nice               nice  169
mer                 mer  160
rennes           rennes  153
bordeaux       bordeaux  144
lille             lille  144
bois               bois  126
marne             marne  123
dijon             dijon  119
nancy             nancy  116
provence       provence  115
```

And this is my code for creating the word cloud

```
library("wordcloud")
library(wordcloud2)


color_range_number<-length(unique(d$freq))
color <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues")[3:7])(color_range_number)[factor(d$freq)]

wordcloud(words =d$word,freq =d$freq,min.freq=1,max.words=100,color=color,random.order=FALSE,rot.per=0.35)
```

But I got this :

[image]

Thank you for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one blue color and only want to change the alpha, you do not even need the `colorRampPalette` function, just the `alpha` function from scales.

```
d <- read.table(text = "
city                   word freq
paris             paris 1250
saint             saint 1247
les                 les  694
marseille     marseille  500
lyon               lyon  312
toulouse       toulouse  226
nantes           nantes  204
strasbourg   strasbourg  177
seine             seine  174
montpellier montpellier  170
nice               nice  169
mer                 mer  160
rennes           rennes  153
bordeaux       bordeaux  144
lille             lille  144
bois               bois  126
marne             marne  123
dijon             dijon  119
nancy             nancy  116
provence       provence  115", header = T)

library(wordcloud)
library(scales)
wordcloud(words =d$word,freq =d$freq,min.freq=1,max.words=100,color=alpha("blue", seq(0.4,1, 0.05)),random.order=FALSE,rot.per=0.35)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, but how about the scale shown in right. I want to get the same plot .

Comment: Well, you could change "blue" to "red" as a start. Furthermore, a geographic plot is way different from a Wordcloud, so I am not sure what you'd exactly want here? As far as I know the wordcloud function does not have an option to add a legend, but you could try to create one manually and add it as a separate plot.